# What is the current state of overlaying information on live TV with Google TV

Tags: google-tv

I am looking for a resource with the current status for the ability to overlay information and forms on top of live tv. This is the most recent info I can find: https://groups.google.com/forum/?fromgroups=#!topic/googletv-android/lu6zMatbbVs

I know that toast notifications are supported, but I see that some apps such as SocialEyez have input forms as well, allowing users to tweet, for example.

Any pointers on how to do this would be greatly appreciated. Every question on SO that says it isn't possible is from 2011.

I am only concerned with the latest versions of the Google TV hardware and software. No need for legacy support.

Answer (score 2):

This is not currently available, but is being worked on. Please enter a feature request in

> http://code.google.com/p/googletv-issues/issues/list

to keep track.

Comment: Thanks. I have starred this issue which describes my desire:
http://code.google.com/p/googletv-issues/issues/detail?id=8&colspec=ID%20Stars%20Type%20Status%20Summary

Answer (score 0):

It looks like as of a few days ago, Google has decided not to pursue fixing the issue posted in the answer... Major suck.

Comment: I thought that I was adding a comment to the other answer and now I can only vote to delete my post rather than actually delete and add as a comment to Joshi's answer... apologies.